# Keep element in view when scrolling, but stop it once it 'collides' with another specified element, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have seen this effect on a few sites ( [CSS Wizardry](http://csswizardry.com/2012/02/pragmatic-practical-font-sizing-in-css/) - watch the logo/nav ) where an element stays in view while scrolling down the page (this is not the hard part) & then stops scrolling when it 'collides' (for want of a better word) with a specified element (the hard part).

I have found two plugins that aim to do just this but do not have all the functionality I need:

**1. jQuery lockScroll**
http://www.anthonymclin.com/code/7-miscellaneous/108-jquery-lockscroll-13

This forces the desired element to have position fixed to begin with, which could mean that if the element starts below the fold, it is never seen.
(Demo: http://www.anthonymclin.com/media/demos/jquery.lockScroll.1.3/)

**2. jQuery fixedScroll** Used on [CSS Wizardry](http://csswizardry.com/2012/02/pragmatic-practical-font-sizing-in-css/)

This forces position fixed again & it needs a top offset in order to work. This offset is applied on DOMReady & moves the element if it is not at that position - it is the offset used when scrolling.

Plugins that I am aware of that do not produce the desired effect:

- https://github.com/dutchcelt/Keep-in-View
- http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/

**I need to be able to have the best of both worlds & unfortunately, I am unable to do that myself, does anyone know of a plugin that I haven't listed or knows a way to modify another?**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like csswizardry is using http://csswizardry.com/wp-content/themes/new/js/jquery.scroll-lock.js

if you change

```
      $(window).bind('load scroll', function(e) {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() + offsetTop >= lockPosition) {
            el.css({ position: "absolute", top: lockPosition });
        } else {
            el.css({ position: "fixed", top: offsetTop });
        }
    });
```

to

```
       $(window).bind('load scroll', function(e) {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() + offsetTop >= maxlockPosition) {
            el.css({ position: "absolute", bottom: maxlockPosition });
        } else if ($(window).scrollTop() + offsetTop >= lockPosition) {
            el.css({ position: "absolute", top: lockPosition });
        } else {
            el.css({ position: "fixed", top: offsetTop });
        }
    });
```

and set maxlockPosition to the position of the element you want to block.

Answer (score -1):

i like this one

http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/

seems twitter's bootstrap is better.

Comment: Dude, I said that Waypoints does not work for what I want. I also saw Twitter bootstrap & am fairly certain that it does not have what I need at all.